# Simplifying jQuery by chaining mouse events

Tags: jquery

I wrote three jQuery functions to target a `span`: one for clicking on the `span`, one for tabbing on the `span`, and one for tabbing/clicking off the `span`. Since this is a lot of jQuery, I'd like to combine it if possible. So I'm wondering if anyone can help me figure out the best way to do so.

**Focus on click:**

```
$(function(){
  $("span#wanttobe").click(function(){
    $("span#wanttobe input").focus();
    $(this).css({
      "border":"1px solid #4D79FF",
      "outline":"none",
      "-webkit-box-shadow": "0 0 4px #4D79FF",
      "-moz-box-shadow": "0 0 4px #4D79FF",
      "box-shadow": "0 0 4px #4D79FF",
      "border-radius": "3px",
      "-moz-border-radius": "3px",
      "-webkit-border-radius": "3px"});
  });
});
```

**Focus on tab:**

```
$(function(){
  $("span#wanttobe").focusin(function(){
    $("span#wanttobe input").focus();
    $(this).css({
      "border":"1px solid #4D79FF",
      "outline":"none",
      "-webkit-box-shadow": "0 0 4px #4D79FF",
      "-moz-box-shadow": "0 0 4px #4D79FF",
      "box-shadow": "0 0 4px #4D79FF",
      "border-radius": "3px",
      "-moz-border-radius": "3px",
      "-webkit-border-radius": "3px"});
  });
});
```

**Focus out:**

```
$(function(){
  $("span#wanttobe").focusout(function(){
    $(this).css({
      "background": "#fff",
      "border": "1px solid #CCD9FF",
      "border-radius": "3px 3px",
      "-moz-border-radius": "3px 3px",
      "-webkit-border-radius": "3px 3px",
      "-moz-box-shadow": "inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.60)",
      "-webkit-box-shadow": "inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.60)",
      "box-shadow": "inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.60)"});
  });
});
```

Comment: Use CSS properly by defining a class in a stylesheet, and use `addClass`/`removeClass`.

Comment: I should've said I tried that but it wasn't working properly. Probably my syntax.

Comment: make sure you leave out the period with `addClass`/`removeClass` (i.e. `addClass('foo')`, not `addClass('.foo')`).

Comment: Yep, got addClass and removeClass down. Now just seeing if I can combine the click and focusin events.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `click()` to `on('click focusin focusout')`.

This will bind the three events at once.